# selenium "Browsing context has been discarded"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the entirety of my script

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

which when run produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wat.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
  File "/home/brevzin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/brevzin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/brevzin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Browsing context has been discarded
```

I just went through an updated everything:

- geckodriver: 0.29.0
- firefox: 87.0
- python: 3.6.9
- selenium: 3.141.0

I've searched through several questions about the same error, and am still completely in the dark as to what the issue is here. I'm barely even doing anything. This is the opening example for Selenium Python, or at least the opening of the opening example.

Comment: "I've searched through several questions about the same error, and am still completely in the dark as to what the issue is here."  I shouldn't have to tell one of the top users on the site to *explain what specific solutions you tried from there and how they failed to address the problem*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Really? Which of them were useful to you? Some of them are about issues with a library I'm not using, some are about clicking of a frame or backing out of a frame, some are about something else entirely. One prominently features a compatibility table which I'm passing (and went ahead and just upgraded everything anyway).

Comment: is that your full code ?

Comment: driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="c:/pathtogeko/gekodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

Comment: try providing the geko path , it might be picking up some non compatible driver from current directory

Comment: @PDHide That's the full code. Tried that, same result.

Comment: Does your Firefox open when you execute?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by <s>burning everything to the ground</s> completely reinstalling everything on my host: I updated Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and then removed Python and all libraries and then reinstalled all of them.

I don't know what the actual problem is, but now at least my trivial example works as expected. I still have no idea what the problem is/was, but maybe this description will help somebody down the road at some point.